# Change the reason of a flag to a question

Tags: support, flags, retracted-flags, flag-reasons

It happened that I flagged a question for a wrong reason and then I want to change my reason. So I know that I have the possibility to cancel my flag using the <kbd>Retract Flag</kbd> button. But after canceling a flag, I have no longer the possibility to flag it again.

So how can we change the reason of the flag?

Comment: You can retract flags, but you cannot change them, unfortunately. What type of flag did you raise? There is usually some other workaround.

Comment: Ah, the flag was on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204485/is-learning-jbpm-good-for-future). For "recommend closure" flags (or whatever they're called now), the reason you pick really doesn't matter much. Generally, you should not retract them unless the question *no longer needs to be closed*. That one still needed to be closed, and I have now done so.

Comment: I wish you could convert a close vote to a dupe vote, if nothing else. Lots of times I've close-voted a question as "needs more details" and then when they add the details it turns out to be a duplicate that wasn't initially obvious.